# How to find least group of students

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

I have this tables:

```
Student - Id, FirstName, LastName, Age
Group - Id, Name
Student_Group - Student_Id, Group_Id
```

I need to find least group of student. I have tried many times. I would be so glad if somebody helped.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your best query attempt.

Comment: What exactly would be the least group?

Comment: What is your definition of "least"? Fewest members? Youngest age?

Comment: Fewest group as student count. My English very bad. That's why I'm sorry

Comment: Could you provide that sample data and expected results that Jarlh asked for, please?

Comment: I tried this:  select [Name] from [Group] join Student_group 
ON [Group].Id = Student_Group.Group_Id
where min(count(Student_Group.Student_Id))
group by Student_Group.Group_Id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to do

```
SELECT top 1 g.name
FROM group g INNER JOIN Student_group sg ON g.id = sg.Group_Id
WHERE count(sg.student_id) >0
ORDER BY count(sg.student_id)
GROUP BY sg.group_id
```

?

If you want also the groups with 0 students you should to do

```
SELECT top 1 g.name
FROM group g INNER JOIN Student_group sg ON g.id = sg.Group_Id
ORDER BY count(sg.student_id)
GROUP BY sg.group_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
--If you just need the group with the least members,
--Group By and Count will work to find the Group with the least members
--Then use select top 1 record and order by GroupCount Ascending
SELECT TOP 1 Group_Id, COUNT(Group_Id) AS [GroupCount]
FROM Student_Group
GROUP BY Group_Id
ORDER BY [GroupCount]
```

Comment: How can you possibly answer this question when we have no idea what "least" is?

Comment: I think "least" is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: That's not what the question asked, it asked "I need to find least group of student. "

Comment: @DavidG No where in the post does it say that.

Comment: @DavidG I based my answer off of what the post does ask for, not some imaginary scenario Oh, look, the OP just verified my answer

Comment: @DavidG I used the information provided in the post.